# "flutter create app_name" not working on Windows 10

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

Whenever I run `"flutter create app_name"` on command prompt, it does nothing! 
It's just stuck there.

Comment: Mine worked eventually, it just took twenty minutes without any user feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure that flutter is not installed under a protected folder like `C:\Program Files`.
2. Check that you have added flutter to PATH in `environment variables`.
3. Make sure that the target folder is not protected.
4. Make sure that  you can access https://pub.dev/

Comment: Do you have to add it to your path if you call it directly, like `c:/data/flutter/bin/flutter create myapp`? I don't want to clutter my path

Comment: Sure, I can't see why you can't do that but a lot of IDE tooling uses flutter commands like `flutter pug get` and `flutter run` and if you don't add flutter to PATH you can't use these conveniently.

Comment: I think android studio uses flutter path from project setup so you shouldn't have trouble there & I know that in IntelliJ IDEs you can have localized PATH variables specified in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated "path" on environment variables.